# A-Z Index of Categories for Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins, indexing, categories

Has anyone seen any plugin for wordpress that provided an alphabetical index of categories that would take you to a page of categories belonging to a particular letter. Basically, there is a list: A B C D ... X Y Z that you can click on, and when you click on A, you go to a page where you see all the categories that start with letter A?

I have searched for over an hour and cannot find this... I started messing around with the MySQL doing this `SELECT term_id as id, name as post_title FROM wp_terms ORDER BY name` but this is also including tags within categories, and I just want to grab the categories.

**Update:**

Ok, so it looks like I can grab just the categories from wp_term_taxonomy via something like this:

```
SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy =  'category'
```

Then, I can take that array and run it here:

```
SELECT term_id, name FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (that-array) ORDER BY name
```

How is that? How to create a new table using what I have above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function and pass a letter as a parameter

```
  function get_category_by_letter($letter){
    $args=array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => 0);

    $categories=get_categories($args);
    foreach($categories as $category) {

    $catname = $category->name;
    $first_letter = substr(strip_tags($catname), 0 , 1); // get the first letter of the category
    if(strcasecmp($first_letter,$letter) != 0) continue; //if not the same letter then loop next NOTE: this is case insensitive comparison
    else{
      $cats[] = $category->term_id; //store category IDs in array
      //$cats[] = $category->name; uncomment this if you want to get category name
      //or you can start your process here and remove the return value  
        }
    }
 return $cats;
}
```

Example usage

```
  $cats = get_category_by_letter('A');
  var_dump($cats);
```

Comment: i have updated it to handle condition of letter in case-insensitive comparison

Comment: Thanks for the response.  One thing that worries me about this approach is performance since you are basically retrieving all the categories and doing a loop on the letter passed.  I am going to have a lot of categories, let's say 1000, especially since tags count as categories in get_categories so was hoping for a different approach.  Anyway I can make a seperate mysql table that just stores categories per letter or something...

Answer (score 0):

you can use transient api for caching your sql query.

Comment: I don't follow, why would I want the added feature of an expiration time.  I am looking to generate a table of categories (not tags) by alphabetical letter. You click on A and see all the categories displayed that start with A. How does transient api connect?